# My UIStepper is not animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistepper

I'm using a `UIStepper` which I added through the storyboard. I had a `IBOulet` reference to my `UITableViewCell` subclass and a `IBAction` when the stepper's value changed.

My problem is that when I touch my `UIStepper`, there is no animation. I'm quite new in iOS dev so I can't find out why.

There is my header file:

```
//CellSubclass.h
@interface SAProductCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *quantityStepper;
- (IBAction)stepperValueChanged:(id)sender;
```

And my implementation:

```
//CellSubclass.m
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier
{
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if (self) {
       self.quantityStepper.minimumValue = 0;
       self.quantityStepper.stepValue = 0;
       self.quantityStepper.value = 1;
   }
   return self;
}
// ...
- (IBAction)stepperValueChanged:(id)sender{
    self.quantity = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:([self.quantityStepper value])] ;
    //[self refreshUI]; --> WORKS FINE !! But there is no animation when I touch down my stepper
}
```

Comment: add some of your code

Comment: Please provide additional information, such as the function that is called when the stepper is tapped, etc. Your question is currently very vague and it's hard for anyone to know the cause of your issue.

Comment: code added as you asked

Comment: What animation are you expecting? `UIStepper` doesn’t have any animation. Do you mean the control doesn’t darken when you touch down on it?

Comment: By the way, you can probably do `self.quantity = @(self.quantityStepper.value);`. The new [literals syntax](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html) is perfect for that kind of thing.